# Installing Raspbian: Missing Configuration Step?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie

So here's the problem... Or maybe blessing depending on how you look at it...

I downloaded the Raspbian Jessie image... And no, not NOOBS; I got tired of NOOBS. After writing the image to the SD card, I set it aside, and it's been about a week since I wrote the image.

Since then, I bought 4 Raspberry Pi 3 Bs, put 2 in their cases, and inserted the SD card on one of them. I plugged in my HDMI cable, then my keyboard, and finally my power cord.

All of a sudden, it started booting up. It booted straight to the desktop that would normally be there AFTER you've set specifics on the traditional blue `raspi-config` screen.

So my question is this: **Did the Foundation decide to write the image file to boot straight to the desktop?**  Don't get me wrong, I enjoy the plug and play aspect, but I was kind of hoping for the traditional set up so I could edit the things I wanted to (like we used to be able to).

I keep running into sources that only talk about NOOBS, or doesn't state the answer to my question. Or perhaps they do and I just don't understand it because of how they wrote their article.

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: You don't need any necessary configuration now so it's booting already to ready OS. If you want some optional configuration run raspi-config yourself.

Comment: In the future, please put a little more effort into writing with good sentence structure and grammar. If you don't care enough to write a proper question, many people won't care enough to answer it.

Comment: I'm doing this on a cell phone. Not everything can be done well on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other OS, Raspbian has some defaults enabled. Since the RPi is geared towards children, those defaults tend to be on the friendlier side.

If you want to edit the defaults, you can change them with *the traditional blue screen* by using the command `sudo raspi-config`.

Comment: It's actually geared toward those whom want to learn basic computing. At least that's my opinion. It just threw me for a loop,  because I have always had to set up everything before Jessie rolled out. And since it was my first time installing everything "from scratch"  without noobs,  it caught me off guard.